# android mapbox: how can i animate markers, like marker falling from the top of screen?

Tags: android, mapbox

My goal is to create a marker on a map with falling animation from the top of screen.
I don't know how to solve it.
How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method:

```
private void dropPinEffect(final Marker marker) {
    // Handler allows us to repeat a code block after a specified delay
    final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final long duration = 1500;

    // Use the bounce interpolator
    final android.view.animation.Interpolator interpolator =
            new BounceInterpolator();

    // Animate marker with a bounce updating its position every 15ms
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            // Calculate t for bounce based on elapsed time
            float t = Math.max(
                    1 - interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                            / duration), 0);
            // Set the anchor
            marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 1.0f + 14 * t);

            if (t > 0.0) {
                // Post this event again 15ms from now.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 15);
            } else { // done elapsing, show window
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
        }
    });
}
```